Sysadmin Privileges Disappear When using database
I have an AD login added to a SQL Server group.
The SQL Server group has the sysadmin role.
When the user logs in they connect correctly
account name    type    privilege   mapped login name   permission path
domain\test     user    admin       domain\test         domain\groupwithsysadmin

When they execute a stored procedure in a user database, it errors out for not having execute permissions.

The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'SomeFunction', database 'SomeDatabase', schema 'Test'.

If I execute as user in the database, the same things happens.
use SomeDatabase 
GO 
EXECUTE AS USER = 'domain\test';  
select Test.SomeFunction ('ComponentTest')
REVERT; 
GO


The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'SomeFunction', database 'SomeDatabase', schema 'Test'.

If I execute as the login it works.
EXECUTE AS login= 'domain\test'; 
select SomeDatabase.Test.SomeFunction ('ComponentTest')
REVERT; 
GO

I am stumped as to why a the login will not carry the sysadmin privileges when using the database.

Is your domain\test User orphaned from the Login?

It is an AD login as part of a group, so was never a login/user on the server/database.

Regardless, whichever Login and User that represents the AD Group. Are they orphaned?

Indeed sounds like the AD group itself is orphaned. Try SELECT dp.name, dp.type, dp.sid, sp.sid AS server_sid, sp.type AS server_type FROM sys.database_principals AS dp LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals AS sp ON dp.sid = sp.sid WHERE dp.principal_id = DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID(); https://dbfiddle.uk/x8WN9yY0 and show us the results, the last two columns will be null if orphaned.

Am seeing no evidence of the user or group in question being orphaned in the database.

Does that query access any object from another database?

Yes, it will also run a stored procedure to read from tables in another database.

Just an FYI, it is possible for AD users/groups to be orphaned, if (for example) systems deleted the user/group and then recreated it, even with the same name the SID will be different.
